# OpenCart 2.3 anchor menu links

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart2.x

Please help with **OpenCart 2.3**. I am creating a Landing Page on this CMS.

There is a menu. Each menu has an anchor address.

The task is this: in a burger, when you click on the menu link, it is necessary that the Scroll anchor goes down to the section with the id and the desired anchor.

In the admin panel in the Menu Builder, I created a "**Home**" menu and a #home link. The section was indicated by **id="home"** Initially, the link on the site was formed as follows:
*.../index.php?route=#home*

I disabled adding this link. Now the link is formed without **index.php**

In file:
*\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\header.tpl*

Wrote menu code:

```
       <nav class="menu">
         <ol class="menu_list">
           <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
             <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
               <li class="menu_item">
                 <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>#" class="menu__link"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
               </li>
             <?php } else { ?>
               <li class="menu_item">
                 <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>#" class="menu__link"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
               </li>
             <?php} ?>
           <?php} ?>
         </ol>
       </nav>
```

I don't know how to correctly write php code after # from value="#home" value in admin panel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUhwI.jpg)